# MySQL UNION/JOIN on the same column

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have a normalization table whose rows are two foreign keys that point to the primary keys in a table of widgets. The idea is that widgets occur in pairs, hence the normalization table has two columns: widget1 and widget2.

```
+--------------------+
| widget1 | widget2  |
+--------------------+
|    1    |    3     |
|    2    |    4     |
+--------------------+
```

Each widget has two columns as well; its primary key and its name. Eg

```
+------------+
| pk | name  |
+------------+
| 1  | Bob   |
| 2  | Joe   |
| 3  | Max   |
| 4  | Tim   |
+------------+
```

I'm trying to build a query to get which name corresponds to which other name, i.e.:

```
+--------------------+
| widget1 | widget2  |
+--------------------+
|   Bob   |   Max    |
|   Joe   |   Tim    |
+--------------------+
```

`UNION`ing two select statements gives one long column. How can I get the desired output? [Here's the SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69b73/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two joins, not a `UNION`:

```
SELECT w1.name, w2.name
FROM   norm
  JOIN widgets w1 ON w1.pk = norm.widget1
  JOIN widgets w2 ON w2.pk = norm.widget2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69b73/2/0).

Comment: Thanks - was having trouble reading the query for a second because no `AS` for the w1 and w2 aliases.